# Protoc generates GRPC .pb.go and grpc.pb.go files in different directories

Tags: grpc, protoc, protobuf-go

I have a GRPC service and associated requests declared in a file called `github.com/myuser/myrepo/protos/iam/v1/service.proto`. The header for this file looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package myrepo.iam.v1;

option go_package = "github.com/myuser/myrepo-go/iam/v1"; // golang
```

Now, when I attempt to compile this using the following protoc command from the `myrepo` directory:

```
find ./protos -type f -name "*.proto" -exec protoc --go_out=./gopb --go-grpc_out=./gopb --go_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo-go {} \;
```

This command works and produces two files:

```
gopb /
- iam /
  - v1 /
    - service.pb.go
- github.com /
  - myuser /
    - myrepo-go /
      - iam /
        - v1 /
          - service_grpc.pb.go
```

Of these files, `service.pb.go` is located correctly but I'm not sure why `service_grpc.pb.go` is located where it is. How can I ensure that both files are written to `gopb/iam/v1/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to duplicate the `--go_opt=module=` flag for gRPC i.e. `--go-grpc_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo-go`

```bash
protoc \
--go_out=./gopb \
--go_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo-go
--go-grpc_out=./gopb \
--go-grpc_opt=module=github.com/myuser/myrepo-go \
service.proto
```

Comment: @woody1193 good catch, apologies

Comment: No worries; there's no compiler in SO to catch typos after all ;)